# How can i write this fraction?

Tags: equations

It would be really helpful if someone could tell me how to write this equation in LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: please show what you tried, it doesn't look hard if you know `\sqrt{...}` makes a square root and `\frac{..}{..}` makes a fraction.

Comment: Welcome! Right now, this is just a do-it-all-for-me which leaves us guessing what you are having trouble with and requires would-be helpers to start from scratch. Please post the code for a minimal document which shows us what you've got so far.

Comment: This might be much easier to read if you can replace the subscripted symbols d_1 and d_2 with two letters, perhaps c and d. (I understand that the context may not allow that. The d_i may have important connotations.)

Comment: \begin{equation}
f(x ; d_1, d_2) = {\frac\sqrt(d_1 x)^d_1 d_2 ^ d_2 }{(d_1 x + d_2)^d_1 + d_2} {xB \frac{d_1}{2},{\frac{d_1}{2}
\end{equation}                                                                                                 I did it like that .. and it wasn't working ..showing error as overfull but thanks for the answer below it worked  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's tricky, but only for making it look better than in the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
f(x;d_{1},d_{2})=
\frac
  {
   \sqrt
     {
      \frac
        {(d_{1}x)_{\vphantom{2}}^{d_{1}}d_{2}^{d_{2}}}
        {(d_{1}x+d_{2})^{d_{1}+d_{2}\mathstrut}}
     }
  }
  {xB\bigl(\frac{d_{1}}{2},\frac{d_{2}}{2}\bigr)}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The indentation helps in keeping track of braces.

The differences with the image are

1. the exponents in the numerator under the square root are at the same level, thanks to `_{\vphantom{2}}`
2. the exponents in the denominator under the square root don't touch the fraction line, thanks to `\mathstrut`
3. the parenthesis after `B` is not far away from it (the original apparently used `\left` and `\right` rather than `\bigl` and `\bigr`).

[image]

Comment: i did it in one line thats why it was saying overfull                                                      
\begin{equation}
f(x ; d_1, d_2) = {\frac\sqrt(d_1 x)^d_1 d_2 ^ d_2 }{(d_1 x + d_2)^d_1 + d_2} {xB \frac{d_1}{2},{\frac{d_1}{2}
\end{equation}                       but thank you so much everyone for your help truely appreciate that